# IE sending wrong content type on redirect using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect, post, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

This is my first time working with XMLHttpRequest directly. Hopefully someone can give me a hint

Scenario:
I'm trying to upload a file to my server using XMLHttpRequest.To do this I:

POST a form ( multipart ) to my server using XMLHttpRequest. This POST works as expected; file is uploaded  and no errors displayed.

Then  my server responds with a redirect. I can see the Internet Explorer executing the redirect with a GET but the content type remained 'multipart'(form the first request ). This causes my server to crash. Content type is set to multipart but no actual information to parse is sent.

The exact same code works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but not with IE.

HTML form

```
<form action="my path" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input  name="import[my_file]" type="file">
</form>
```

ROR Code is pretty straight fw

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  def my_action
    file = params[:import][:my_file]
    ...
    redirect_to :action => :other_action
  end

  def other_action
    render :text => 'Just an ilustration'
  end
end
```

Javascript Code

```
var form = $('<The form containing the file input>')[0];
var formData = new FormData(form);
var url = $(this).attr('action');

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var response = request.open('POST', url, true);

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    // Code when it is done
  }
}

request.send(formData);
return false;
```

Here both requests: POST to upload file and GET for redirect:

[image]

These are the POST headers, request and response:

[image: Post Request]

[image: Post Response]

These are GET headers, request and response. You can see how the Content type is set to multipart-formdata, which is incorrect.

[image: Get Request]
[image: Get Response]

In order to make sure the redirect along with XMLHttpRequest are somehow the "cause" of this problem, I got rid of the XMLHttpRequest code and let the form behave normally. The GET call for the redirect had the correct content type ( text/html ). It worked correctly.

Any idea what I could do to make IE use the correct content type in the GET request for the redirect after the POST, using the XMLHttpRequest?

( Sorry for the ultra long post )

Comment: Just a random shot, but have you tried setting the form's `encoding` property to `"multipart/form-data"` as well?

Comment: You should probably be redirecting with a [303 See Other HTTP response](https://httpstatuses.com/303). It specifically states: "primarily used to allow the output of a POST action to redirect the user agent to a selected resource, since doing so provides the information corresponding to the POST response in a form that can be separately identified, bookmarked, and cached, independent of the original request."

Comment: @idbehold Thanks for your comment. I tried with 303 and got the same behavior. Content-Type for the redirect (GET) still is multipart. Still getting the same error. I even tried with status codes from this [list](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html ) (300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 307) For some of them, browser won't follow the URL, but I think that is expected. But when it does follow, content type is still multipart.

Comment: @stevenelberger Thanks for your response. Not sure if I fully understand your suggestion. You mean make the form look like this?  `<form action="my_path" encoding="multipart/form-data" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">` I tried that as well.. No luck ..

Comment: jquery sets the content-type for ajax requests by default, maybe because of this? https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/